# Select one grid cell in R

Tags: r, cell, raster

Is it possible to select only one grid cell from a raster brick and get a raster brick for this particular grid cell ?

I have to do a very computational expensive task on a raster brick and need to test the script on one grid cell before.

I don't like the result of the extract function.

Example from this format :

```
> prec_stack
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4, 366  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -6, -5.5, 40.5, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :   X2020.01.01,   X2020.01.02,   X2020.01.03,   X2020.01.04,   X2020.01.05,   X2020.01.06,   X2020.01.07,   X2020.01.08,   X2020.01.09,   X2020.01.10,   X2020.01.11,   X2020.01.12,   X2020.01.13,   X2020.01.14,   X2020.01.15, ... 
min values :  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  6.631103e-04,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  3.436539e-01,  4.741280e-03,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  8.816075e-04,  1.909899e-01,  7.564928e-01, ... 
max values :  8.832944e-04,  1.665335e-13,  4.644275e-03,  1.665335e-13,  2.981438e-03,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  6.721702e-01,  1.005035e-02,  2.429699e-03,  1.665335e-13,  2.098144e-03,  6.070088e-01,  1.907934e+00, ...
```

Comment: You need to share example data and code that you want fix, debug or optimize to get the help which you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is achually very simple.

You just need to use the brackets, define the row and columm of the selected cell, and add the argument `drop=FALSE`,  like this:

```
   SelectedBrick <- YourBrick[CellRow, CellCol, drop=FALSE]
```

The result will be a raster brick (SelectedBrick) with the selected cell for all layers.

Comment: Thank you ! But how to know the row and column of a particular gridcell?

Comment: Did the code help you? If so, please recommend the answer. Regarding the second question in this comment, the answer will depend upon your criteria to define the target pixel, if you don't mind. It could be the center pixel, a corner pixel, pixels with specific values, or specific coordinates. For each of these cases, the answer will differ. I recommend that you open a new question specifying what you need.